# how to return Javascript variable in JSON format PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to **return** Javascript variable in JSON format in PHP.

Below is my Javascript code which returns Longitude and Latitude.

```
function showPosition(){
        if(navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

                 var positionInfo = "Your current position is (" + "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ", " + "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude + ")";
                //document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = positionInfo;


            });
        } else{
            alert("Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 geolocation.");
        }
    }
    showPosition();
    //document.write(positionInfo);
```

> How can i get the values of variable `position.coords.latitude` and `position.coords.longitude` as response in json format using php

**Please note:** We are calling this php script in background, so solution of fetching the variables on html input fields is not a viable solution for us.

Comment: This JS returns nothing ... and further the relationship to php is neither present, nor explained.

Comment: I am trying to learn javascript and php.  i don't know the solution. I have value in positioninfo and i don't know how to use this php. Please help if you can.

Comment: This is sample demo - https://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/

Comment: Your question fails to explain if you want to SEND the values to a php script, or RECEIVE them from there. (Code indicates transfer to php, but bytext suggests fetching from.)

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is to issue an AJAX request and send the data to your PHP script:

```
var locationData = {'latitude':position.coords.latitude,'longitude':position.coords.longitude}; //Your data in JSON
locationData = JSON.stringify(locationData); //Your data as a JSON string

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //Create a new ajax request

  xhttp.open("POST", "script.php", true); //Set the method to POST, and the location of the php script

  xhttp.send(locationData); //Send data in string format
```

I recommend that you read more about [AJAX requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started), or use an alternative JavaScript library for simpler syntax.